# How to find g(x) and its remainder

Tags: polynomials

The question is as shown below.

> When a polynomial $g(x)$ is divided by $x^2 - 4$, the remainder is $\alpha x + \beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant. Determine the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given that $x + 2$ is a factor of $g(x)$, and also that when $g(x)$ is divided by $x-2$ the remainder is $6$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried using partial fraction but I think it cannot work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $ g(x) = f(x) (x^2 - 4 )  + \alpha x + \beta $.

What is $g(-2)$? There are 2 possible interpretations.

What is $ g (2)$? There are 2 possible interpretations.

Hence, solve the simultaneous equations.